# How can I speed up my printing code in .Net

Tags: .net, optimization, printing

I have successfully built a .NET program to print client statements using the PrintDocument component. The print job consists of plain text and bitonal(black and white) TIFF images but the problem I am having is that it is too slow. I can't be the first one to run into this. Are there ways to improve the performance of the .Net printdocument component or should I abandon this method for another (or is my only true option 3rd party libraries that are specialized for printing).

I am trying to write a replacement for a program that we currently pay a vendor a huge amount of money for (this is only one of the things that the vendor does for us).  Their program  takes only 2 and half minutes to print 7000 pages of statements (their output is PCL 5).  My program using the .Net PrintDocument Component takes a little over an hour to do the same job.

Are there any good open source or paid PCL or printing libraries that can be used with .net?

Comment: What operating system are you running? Windows XP has notoriously poor TIFF support because it is using an old version of the libraries. This is improved in Vista and later versions. Likely the .NET components are using the built-in Windows libraries, but your vendor is using a proprietary version to read the TIFF files.

Comment: Using Windows 7 Pro,  I did remove the TIFF parts to see if I would see a significant speed increase but I did not. Even plain text was slow compared to what the vendor is doing.

Comment: Well I have been messing with this and did speed it up significantly by changing my printer driver (the one I was using was for XP not windows 7).  Now my process only takes 9 minutes.  I would still like to improve this as much as possible so I am still looking for general tips on optimizing code that uses printdocument code.

Comment: @user2297566 I know its quite late, but still might be helpful for someone.  Cache PageSettings of PrintDocument to avoid repeated calls.